# Maximum number of parties in MTG

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander, mtg-multiplayer

Apologies if this has been answered, but

How many parties can you have in MTG?
I’m aware that a party consists of 0-4 so cleric, rogue, wizard and warrior.

But if I have a full party and say another 4 creatures, (1 from each) does that mean I have 2 parties or is the maximum allowed 1 party?

Comment: This is a question about Magic the Gathering rules, which have always been on-topic on _Board & Card Games_ - totally irrespective of the fact(s) that the mechanic in question is inspired by similar story tropes as Dungeons&Dragons (and that there is a cross-over set soon to be released, and that the relative timing is probably no coincidence).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There isn't a card nor an entry in the rules that mention multiples parties, therefore the number of parties you can form is irrelevant.

Also, rule 700.8a state s

> The calculation of the number of creatures in a player’s party is performed automatically by the game and results in a **number between zero and four**. Players don’t declare which **specific** creatures they control are in their party.

The party mechanic doesn't care about the individual creatures but cares about the diversity in your whole pool of creatures.

Answer (score 11):

**One per player.**

The text of rule 700.8 makes this clear (emphasis mine):

> 700.8. Some cards refer to the number of creatures in **a player’s party**. A player’s party consists of up to one creature that player controls for each of the following four creature types: Cleric, Rogue, Warrior, and Wizard.

Throughout 700.8, the party is always referred to in a one-to-one relationship with the player. A player has exactly one party (even if it's empty); phrasings like "a player's party", "that player's party", etc. would make no sense if they could have more than one.

Despite the common meaning of "party" and the flavor it evokes, party is not a mechanic for grouping creatures into discrete entities, it is a count maintained by the player who controls those creatures.